# webapp2 error deleting cookies

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

I'm using webapp2 with python 2.7 on GAE 1.7.5. I set cookies like so:

```
self.response.set_cookie('clientID', self.request.get('clientID'), max_age=constants.day_timeout)
```

but when I try to delete them like so:

```
self.response.unset_cookie('clientID')
```

or like:

```
self.response.delete_cookie('clientID')
```

I get `exception removing client cookies`

Not sure what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that when getting values from the request object, they are in unicode format. If your clientID is in unicode, then it must be converted to string :

```
value = str(self.request.get('clientID')) 
self.response.set_cookie(key = 'clientID', 
                         value=value 
                         )
```

Here is the webapp2 documentation on [setting cookies](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/response.html#setting-cookies).